# MySQL Query to rank based on number of similar tags

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I was hoping for someone with more advanced MySQL knowledge than myself to help guide me in how to do the following.

Lets say I have Table #1, videos:

```
Video ID
Video Name etc
```

I also have Table #2, tags

```
Tag ID
Tag Name
```

I have a third table which links each video to one or more tags:

```
ID (primary and autoincremented)
Tag ID
Video ID
```

Now I'm able to find similar videos (based on ranking how many videos share the largest number of tags as one) using the above in conjunction with PHP, but this involves a number of queries and I feel it could be done more elegantly through mysql queries alone. I'd like to look through the videos and find the ones most similar based on the quantity of tags they have in common with one another.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Could you provide a sample of input data and desired output data?

Comment: Please show queries you are currently using in addition to what was asked about by @TrippKinetics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say the video is "Gravity" and the VIDEO_ID of Gravity is 4321.

```
SELECT COUNT(res.TAG_ID), res.VIDEO_ID
FROM tag_link_table res
  INNER JOIN tag_link_table target
    ON target.VIDEO_ID = 4321 AND res.TAG_ID = target.TAG_ID
GROUP BY res.VIDEO_ID
ORDER BY COUNT(res.TAG_ID) DESC
```

Comment: Marlin's query is correct, but it's worth noting two things. One, this would be an EXTREMELY expensive query to execute if you ever wanted to compute more than one video at a time (eg video_id = ?). It's an inherently combinatorical problem. In fact it's essentially a k-nearest neighbors problem, which I would very strongly recommend not running in SQL, unless you only need to look at one video at a time. If that's the case, point two: make sure you create an index on tag_link_table which contains TAG_ID (or, perhaps even better, one on (VIDEO_ID ,TAG_ID) and one on TAG_ID).

Comment: Yes the tag_link_table definitely needs an index on VIDEO_ID and another index on TAG_ID.

Comment: I just created a schema for the question on SqlFiddle but Marlin's answer came first. So, i combined query and schema here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/318d5/3

Comment: Between an index on VIDEO_ID and an index on TAG_ID vs a multi-column index on (VIDEO_ID, TAG_ID) and another on TAG_ID, I think I'd do the later... benefits of covering index without an index merge. Also, you can get rid of the auto increment on tag_link_table and Pk off of (VIDEO_ID, TAG_ID)... save a bit of space and help accuracy. Might affect write speeds a little bit, but not enough that I'd hesitate to Pk those two columns and remove the auto increment one.

Comment: It's important to consider indexing multiple fields, since too many young programmers only index one field.  Understand that if you have an index on (VIDEO_ID, TAG_ID) the DB can use it as an index on just VIDEO_ID.  That is, if the DB needs an index on VIDEO_ID, it can use the compound index because VIDEO_ID is first, and so it will not be lacking for a VIDEO_ID index.

Comment: I don't think this query can use a (VIDEO_ID, TAG_ID) index except as just an index on VIDEO_ID.  First it uses an index on VIDEO_ID to find the records in target to get the collection of tags.  A (VIDEO_ID, TAG_ID) index would get the tags in order, but that does not help when it goes to the res table (literally back to the tag_link_table table) to find the result set.

Comment: A (VIDEO_ID, TAG_ID) index does make a find primary key instead of the auto-increment field.  That would technically be the most optimized solution, and would not likely run into a problem.  However, there is a school of thought to always have an auto-increment primary key.  Neither alternative is absolutely right or wrong, or even best.  If you always have an auto-increment primary key you will never run into a situation where you greatly regret doing so.  Yet evanv is right and helpful with his suggestion.